# Odoo Custom module creation

Tags: python, odoo, crm

I'm trying to create a custom module using odoo (I'm coding with vs code), My project path is is like that "Odoo/Server/Addons/HelloWorld"  ,When I try to run the odoo server , it opens correctly but I do not find the module "Hello world" .

Comment: Make sure `Odoo/Server/Addons` is in addons path

Answer (score 0):

Should've add more information regarding the problem.As maybe you cannot find you module in odoo's App or you aren't able to file in your filesystem. Let me address both scenerio.

### First for Odoo's App module

In this section you will find solution regarding module doesn't being able install as it absent from list of application odoo view.

- Make sure Odoo/Server/Addons is against addons_path like(use absolute-path of the directory or folder)

  ```
   addons_path=Odoo/Server/Addons
  ```
- If path is correctly added. Make sure to click on "Update Apps List" after restarting the odoo service.

### Second for module not showing within Filesystem

In this section you will find solution regarding module cannot be found within filesystem.

- Due to incorrect scaffold command, maybe the you make path syntax error. the module is created but wasn't add to desired location.Correct scaffold for your path will be

  python3 odoo-bin  Odoo/Server/Addons/
- Issue may reside due to wrong module structure. For that you need to refer to documentation to you odoo version but mostly are the same. Here the [Coding guidelines - Odoo](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/contributing/development/coding_guidelines.html).

  ```
   addons/plant_nursery/
   |-- __init__.py
   |-- __manifest__.py
   |-- controllers/
   |   |-- __init__.py
   |   |-- plant_nursery.py
   |   |-- portal.py
   |-- data/
   |   |-- plant_nursery_data.xml
   |   |-- plant_nursery_demo.xml
   |   |-- mail_data.xml
   |-- models/
   |   |-- __init__.py
   |   |-- plant_nursery.py
   |   |-- plant_order.py
   |   |-- res_partner.py
   |-- report/
   |   |-- __init__.py
   |   |-- plant_order_report.py
   |   |-- plant_order_report_views.xml
   |   |-- plant_order_reports.xml (report actions, paperformat,                    ...)
   |   |-- plant_order_templates.xml (xml report templates)
   |-- security/
   |   |-- ir.model.access.csv
   |   |-- plant_nursery_groups.xml
   |   |-- plant_nursery_security.xml
   |   |-- plant_order_security.xml
   |-- static/
   |   |-- img/
   |   |   |-- my_little_kitten.png
   |   |   |-- troll.jpg
   |   |-- lib/
   |   |   |-- external_lib/
   |   |-- src/
   |   |   |-- js/
   |   |   |   |-- widget_a.js
   |   |   |   |-- widget_b.js
   |   |   |-- scss/
   |   |   |   |-- widget_a.scss
   |   |   |   |-- widget_b.scss
   |   |   |-- xml/
   |   |   |   |-- widget_a.xml
   |   |   |   |-- widget_a.xml
   |-- views/
   |   |-- plant_nursery_menus.xml
   |   |-- plant_nursery_views.xml
   |   |-- plant_nursery_templates.xml
   |   |-- plant_order_views.xml
   |   |-- plant_order_templates.xml
   |   |-- res_partner_views.xml
   |-- wizard/
   |   |--make_plant_order.py
   |   |--make_plant_order_views.xml
  ```

Comment: the folder I'm   working on it is  a copy of the original folder .

Comment: Can you verify its absolute path is added  in odoo.conf ?? if so make sure its AFTER odoo base addons path are separated by comma without space.